# show 4 website in 1 page with no scrollbar?

Tags: html, iframe

i have a webpage including 4 different iframe webpages i want that all pages should show 100% in one page but overall page size should be shrink. 
Mean all pages shows 25%; 
when i give a size to iframe then it's shows scroll bar what to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible unless you can edit the source code of all four loaded web pages. There is no "zoom" parameter/attribute for an iframe, so the pages that are loaded would need to autosize to fit, themselves.

Comment: i have 4 website like
http://www.vecteezy.com 
http://www.cgvector.com 
http://www.vector.tutsplus.com 
http://www.msn.com 

i don't have source code of these website...

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods for hiding the scrollbars from an inline frame. Here they are:

```
**
```

**Using scrolling="no". This is how to remove iframe scrollbars in HTML 4.1 (the current version of HTML at the time of writing).


    Using overflow:hidden. This is how to hide scrollbars using CSS (Cascading Style Sheets)


    Using seamless="seamless". This attribute was introduced in the HTML version 5 working draft. Therefore, to cater for future browsers, this code should be included.**

**

Which one to use?

You can safely use all three at the same time. Having said that, if you prefer to validate your webpages using the W3C validator, you should only use the method that aligns with the version of HTML that you are validating against. Therefore, if you're using HTML 4.1, use scrolling="no". If you're using HTML 5, use seamless="seamless".

In any case, you can also use overflow:hidden along with any other code. Actually, you will usually find that this overrides the HTML and hides any scrollbars that have been defined.

Comment: If I understood the OP correctly, he doesn't want to hide the scrollbar - he wants to eliminate the need for it by resizing the *contents* of the iframe to fit.

Comment: Yes Mamoud al qudsi you are right i want to show all pages shrink in my 1 screen.